# Haskell stack in a project-specific location

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm following the guide [here](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#start-your-new-project), which tells me:

> The stack setup will download the compiler if necessary in an isolated
> location (default ~/.stack) that won't interfere with any system-level
> installations. (For information on installation paths, please use the
> stack path command.).

I'm trying to use a custom location, such as `~/myproject/myenvironment`.  When I use the `stack path` command, I see a lot of paths, such as `stack-root`, `project-root`, and `config-location`, but I don't see any way of setting the custom location with `stack path`.  How can I sequester my stack to not operate out of `~/.stack` but by a custom location? What arguments can I give `stack update` for example to localize to `~/myproject/myenvironment`?

Comment: Did you try to change the [`$STACK_ROOT`](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1148) environment variable?

Comment: This can be configured with the `STACK_ROOT` environment variable or the `--stack-root` option.

Comment: Perhaps you already know this, but Stack isn't really supposed to be configured this way in normal usage.  The `~/.stack` directory is intended as a user-wide (rather than project-wide) cache of GHC versions and packages.  If you are developing multiple projects and reconfiguring `STACK_ROOT` for each one, you're doing it wrong.  The only time you might want to configure a project-specific `STACK_ROOT` is if you're doing something unusual, like configuring a self-contained virtual machine image or archive file for other developers or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, this is all helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Set the environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) `STACK_ROOT`.
The parameter `--stack-root` of `stack` command works for one call only.
The `stack path --stack-root` command is used only to list the variable.

### Resources:

[Haskell Stack User Guide chapter Setting stack root location](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#setting-stack-root-location)
https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1148

```
stack --help
...
  --stack-root STACK-ROOT  Absolute path to the global stack root directory
                           (Overrides any STACK_ROOT environment variable)
...
stack path --help
...
  --stack-root             Global stack root directory
...
```