# How to change 'sr' directory when installing Facebook / Duckling?

Tags: windows, facebook, haskell, cmd, haskell-stack

I'm setting up [Facebook / Duckling](https://github.com/facebook/duckling) using the [Quickstart](https://github.com/facebook/duckling#quickstart):

```
stack build
stack exec duckling-example-exe
```

When I run the previous commands, the `sr` folder is created in `c:\` directory, which is not desired.

How can I tell the compiler to use a custom directory for the `sr` folder?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70621558/1013393.